# Python-OpenCV dilate and erode functions don't modify anything

Tags: python, opencv

Given the code below, the cv2.dilate and cv2.erode functions in python return the same image I send to it.  What am I doing wrong? I am using OpenCV3.0.0. and numpy1.9.0 on iPython 2.7

```
im = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.uint8)
im[50:,50:] = 255
dilated = cv2.dilate(im, (11,11))
print np.array_equal(im, dilated)
```

Which returns:

```
True
```

{Edited}
The other dilate post represents a question of kernel datatype.  This post actually reflects a function call error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't cv2 dilate actually affect my image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270937/why-doesnt-cv2-dilate-actually-affect-my-image)

Comment: My thought was that you didn't specify the dtype of the kernel so it might default to something else than `uint8`. But it might just be that you don't correctly specify the kernel; could you try with `np.ones((11, 11), dtype=np.uint8)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function requires a kernel, not a kernel size.  So a correct function call would be below.

```
dilated = cv2.dilate(im, np.ones((11, 11)))
```

Comment: *Merely specifying a kernel in the function call results in a type int tuple which is not compatible with the function* - I would consider rewording this because that's not correct.  You're supposed to specify a kernel in the input, but the OP is not doing that as it's a tuple.  What I think you meant to say is specifying a tuple of `(11,11)` is incorrect and that a proper kernel should be specified (i.e. `np.ones((11,11))`).  BTW, specifying a `dtype` of `uint8` is superfluous in this case.  However, I gave you a +1 because the code you wrote is correct in getting the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a proper kernel. It can be rectangular, circular, etc.

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
im = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.uint8)
im[50:,50:] = 255
dilated = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your second line where you modify the array. Probably the data type gets infected.

Comment: No. It isn't working because the OP didn't specify the kernel properly. See the OP's answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

the function has to be called this way:
cv2.dilate(img (input), kernel, iterations = number (how many times you want to apply the filter)